# CSS: Button edges are lined up perfectly in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following problem: I have created a search bar and a search button next to it. Actually, it's the FontAwesome search icon with some padding space around it. In Chromium-based browsers the search button is lined up perfectly with the search bar but not in Firefox. How to fix that?

```css
#searchfield {
 width: 200px;
 height: 40px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: rgb(192,0,0);
 font-size: 110%;
 color: black;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border-width: 2px;
 background-color: transparent;
 border-right-width: 0px;
 border-top-right-radius: 0%;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
}

#searchbutton {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: white;
 font-size: 110%;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background-color: rgb(192,0,0);
 border-radius: 4px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0%;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
}
```

```html
<input id="searchfield" type="search" placeholder="Search"/><a id="searchbutton" title="Search">S</a>
```

I don't want the FontAwesome icon to cause any problems so I replaced it with an 'S'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to #searchbutton `vertical-align: text-bottom;` they are lined up perfectly.
It works for me in Firefox.
To set this property just in this browser, you can put this code in your CSS:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
    #searchbutton {
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
    }
}
```